# Why is my UWP game slower in release than in debug mode?

Tags: c++, uwp, directx-11, query-performance

I'm trying to do an UWP game, and i came accross a problem where my game is much slower in release mode than it is in debug mode.

My game will draw a 3D view (Dungeon master style) and will have an UI part that draws over the 3D view. Because the 3D view can slow down to a small amount of frames per seconds (FPS), i decided to make my game running the UI part always at 60 FPS.

Here is how the main gameloop looks like, in some pseudo code:

```
Gameloop start
  Update game datas
  copy actual finished 3D view from buffer to screen
  draw UI part
  3D view loop start
    If no more time to draw more textures on the 3D view exit 3D view loop
    Draw one texture to 3D view buffer
  3D view loop end --> 3D view loop start
Gameloop end --> Gameloop start
```

Here are the actual update and render functions:

```cpp
    void Dungeons_of_NargothMain::Update() 
    {
        m_ritonTimer.startTimer(static_cast<int>(E_RITON_TIMER::UI));

        m_ritonTimer.frameCountPlusOne((int)E_RITON_TIMER::UI_FRAME_COUNT);
        m_ritonTimer.manageFramesPerSecond((int)E_RITON_TIMER::UI_FRAME_COUNT);

        m_ritonTimer.manageFramesPerSecond((int)E_RITON_TIMER::LABY_FRAME_COUNT);

        if (m_sceneRenderer->m_numberTotalOfTexturesToDraw == 0 ||
            m_sceneRenderer->m_numberTotalOfTexturesToDraw <= m_sceneRenderer->m_numberOfTexturesDrawn)
        {
            m_sceneRenderer->m_numberTotalOfTexturesToDraw = 150000;
            m_sceneRenderer->m_numberOfTexturesDrawn = 0;
        }

    }

    // RENDER
    bool Dungeons_of_NargothMain::Render() 
    {
        //********************************//
        // Render UI part here            //
        //********************************//


        //**********************************//
        // Render 3D view to 960X540 screen //
        //**********************************//
        m_sceneRenderer->setRenderTargetTo960X540Screen(); // 3D view buffer screen

        bool screen960GotFullDrawn = false;
        bool stillenoughTimeLeft = true;

        while (stillenoughTimeLeft && (!screen960GotFullDrawn))
        {
            stillenoughTimeLeft = m_ritonTimer.enoughTimeForOneMoreTexture((int)E_RITON_TIMER::UI);
            screen960GotFullDrawn = m_sceneRenderer->renderNextTextureTo960X540Screen();
        }

        if (screen960GotFullDrawn)
            m_ritonTimer.frameCountPlusOne((int)E_RITON_TIMER::LABY_FRAME_COUNT);

        return true;
    }
```

I removed what is not essential.

Here is the timer part (RitonTimer):

```cpp
    #pragma once

    #include "pch.h"
    #include <wrl.h>
    #include "RitonTimer.h"

    Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::RitonTimer()
    {
        initTimer();
        if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcGameStartTime))
        {
            throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
        }
    }

    void Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::startTimer(int timerIndex)
    {
        if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcNowTime))
        {
            throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
        }
        m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex] = m_qpcNowTime.QuadPart;
        m_framesPerSecond[timerIndex] = 0;
        m_frameCount[timerIndex] = 0;
    }

    void Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::resetTimer(int timerIndex)
    {
        if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcNowTime))
        {
            throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
        }
        m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex] = m_qpcNowTime.QuadPart;
        m_framesPerSecond[timerIndex] = m_frameCount[timerIndex];
        m_frameCount[timerIndex] = 0;
    }

    void Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::frameCountPlusOne(int timerIndex)
    {
        m_frameCount[timerIndex]++;
    }

    void Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::manageFramesPerSecond(int timerIndex)
    {
        if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcNowTime))
        {
            throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
        }
        m_qpcDeltaTime = m_qpcNowTime.QuadPart - m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex];

        if (m_qpcDeltaTime >= m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart)
        {
            m_framesPerSecond[timerIndex] = m_frameCount[timerIndex];
            m_frameCount[timerIndex] = 0;
            m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex] += m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart;
            if ((m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex] + m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart) < m_qpcNowTime.QuadPart)
                m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex] = m_qpcNowTime.QuadPart - m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart;
        }
    }

    void Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::initTimer()
    {
        if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&m_qpcFrequency))
        {
            throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
        }

        m_qpcOneFrameTime = m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart / 60;
        m_qpc5PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpcOneFrameTime / 20;
        m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpcOneFrameTime / 10;
        m_qpc95PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpcOneFrameTime - m_qpc5PercentOfOneFrameTime;
        m_qpc90PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpcOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime;
        m_qpc80PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpcOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime;
        m_qpc70PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpcOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime;
        m_qpc60PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpc70PercentOfOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime;
        m_qpc50PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpc60PercentOfOneFrameTime - m_qpc10PercentOfOneFrameTime;
        m_qpc45PercentOfOneFrameTime = m_qpc50PercentOfOneFrameTime - m_qpc5PercentOfOneFrameTime;
    }


    bool Dungeons_of_Nargoth::RitonTimer::enoughTimeForOneMoreTexture(int timerIndex)
    {
        while (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcNowTime));

        m_qpcDeltaTime = m_qpcNowTime.QuadPart - m_qpcStartTime[timerIndex];

        if (m_qpcDeltaTime < m_qpc45PercentOfOneFrameTime)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

In debug mode the game's UI works at 60 FPS, and the 3D view is about 1 FPS on my PC. But even there i'm not sure why i have to stop my texture drawing at 45% of one game time and call present,  to get the 60 FPS,  if i wait longer i only get 30 FPS. (this valor is set in "enoughTimeForOneMoreTexture()" in RitonTimer.

In Release mode it drops dramatically, having like 10 FPS for the UI part, 1 FPS for the 3D part. I tried to find why for the last 2 days, didn't find it.

Also i have another small question:  How do i tell visual studio that my game is actually a game and not an app ?  Or does Microsoft do the "switch" when i send my game to their store ?

Here i have put my game on my OneDrive so everyone can download the source files and try to compile it, and see if you get the same results as me:

OneDrive link:   https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj7wxGmZTdftgZAZT5YAbLDxbtMNVg

compile in either x64 Debug,  or x64 Release mode.

**UPDATE:**

I think i found the explanation why my game is slower in release mode. 
The CPU is probably not waiting for the drawing instruction to be done, but simply adds it to a list which will be forward to the GPU at it's own pace in a separate task (or maybe the GPU does that cache himself). That would explain it all.

My plan was to draw the UI first and then to draw as many textures from the 3D view as possible till 95% of a 1/60th second frame time passed and then present it to the swapchain. The UI would always be at 60 FPS and the 3D view would be as fast as the system allows it (also at 60FPS if it can all be drawn in 95% of the frame time).
This didn't work because it probbably cached all the instructions my 3D view had (i was testing with 150000 BIG texture draw instructions for the 3D view) in one frame time, and so of course the UI was as slow as the 3D view at the end, or close to.

That is also why even in debug mode i didn't get 60FPS when i waited for 95% of a frame time, i had to wait for 45% of a frame time to get my 60 FPS i wanted for the UI.

I tested it with a lower value in release mode to verify that theory, and indeed i also get 60 FPS for the UI when i stop the Drawings at only 15% of a frame time.

I tought it worked like this only in DirectX12.

Comment: It is quite hard to follow what the code is doing. What do you mean by "render one more texture"? Why are you only sending a subset of the draw calls? There are also some strange things (at least in the embedded code, didn't look at the link), like the `while` loop wrapping `QueryPerformanceCounter` (the docs say it cannot fail). I would suggest simplifying or bisecting the code further until you narrow down the culprit.

Comment: Is it slower when you disable optimization and run in release mode?

Comment: Yes, i tried disabling all optimisations to have it like in debug mode, it's still the same.

Comment: @Acorn:  I render first the UI parts, then i render the textures, one by one, from the 3D part into a back-buffer,  as long as there is still enough time in the frame (trying to target 60 FPS for the UI part). When all textures of the 3D part (could be affter a fiew UI frames) are drawn,  i switch the 3D back-buffer with the front 3D buffer, like a swapchain does it for the main screen, and the front 3D view is Always drawn with the UI part.
The while loop arorund the queryperformanceCounter was just a try of me to fix my problem, i forgot to remove it,  but it should not add to the problem.

Comment: I'm really concerned that the game's 3d content slows down to "a small amount of frames per seconds" - that is an obvious sign that there's something really wrong with your code.

Comment: For rendering textures like you're doing, you don't need to enter a loop and check if you still have time, you will have time to render your full screen once per frame. You will actually have plenty of time remaining. In my own game, a roguelike, I can fill the screen with 32x32 tiles, that's several hundred tiles and it runs at 144Hz. And my game is written in C# with DirectX interop (via SharpDX). That is with some optimization admittedly - I've used 2 approaches, firstly a chunk approach, and the new approach, the whole screen is one texture, and each tike is a lookup in shader.

Comment: However, even if you don't bother with reducing draw calls, you should be still OK, as you can do at least 5000 draw calls at 60fps (C#). And I think C++ can get up to 10,000 for DX11.

Comment: I'll take a look, but I'm not very good with C++, I've only done about 50 hours with the language and it frustrates me, but I might be able to identify some architectural issues.

Comment: @Gavin Williams:  The 3D view will be like the old games Dungeon master, Eye of the Beholder …  Not in real 3D like the modern clones do it (Legend of Grimrock …), but using precalculated 2D bitmaps.  The old games, (DM, EotB..) are using a rather small field of view, like 5X5 squares or so. I want to create a deeper one, Something like 15X15, which will take a LOT more bitmaps to draw each frame.

I tried to replace the amount of textures it draws with a fix number, with a simple For loop, and then it works almost the same in release mode, but it's still about 10% slower.

Answer (score 2):

"How do i tell visual studio that my game is actually a game and not an app" - there's no difference, a game is an app.

I have your code running at 300-400 FPS now in debug mode.

Firstly I commented out your code that checks if you've got time to render another texture. Don't do that. Everything the player sees should render within a single frame. If your frame is taking more than 16ms (with 60fps target) look for  expensive operations, or calls that are made repeatedly, possibly adding up to some unexpected cost. Look for code that might be doing something repeatedly when it only needs to do it once per frame or per resize. etc

So the issue is that you were rendering very large textures and a lot of them. You want to avoid overdraw (rendering a pixel where you've already rendered a pixel). You can have a bit of overdraw and that's sometimes preferable to being pedantic. But you were drawing 1000x2000 textures over and over again. So you were absolutely killing the pixel shader. It just can't render that many pixels. I didn't bother looking at the code that tries to control texture rendering based on frame time remaining. For what you're trying to do, that's not helpful.

Inside your render method comment out the while and if/else sections and use this to draw an array of your textures ..

```
// set sprite dimensions
int w = 64, h = 64;
for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
    {

        m_sceneRenderer->renderNextTextureTo960X540Screen(x*64, y*64, w, h);
    }
}
```

and in RenderNextTextureToScreen(int x, int y, int w, int h) ..

```
    m_squareBuffer.sizeX = w; // 1000;
    m_squareBuffer.sizeY = h; // 2000;
    m_squareBuffer.posX = x; // (float)(rand() % 1920);
    m_squareBuffer.posY = y; // (float)(rand() % 1080);
```

See how this code renders much smaller textures, the textures are 64x64 and there's no overdraw.

And just be aware that the GPU isn't all powerful, it can do a lot if you use it right, but if you just throw crazy operations at it, you can grind it to a halt, just like with the CPU. So try to render things that 'look normal', that you can imagine being in a game. You'll learn in time what's sensible and what isn't.

The most likely explanation for the code running slower in release mode is that your timing and rendering limiter code was broken. It wasn't working properly because the 3d view was running at 1fps, so then who knows what it's behaviour is. With the changes I've made, the program seems to run faster in release mode as expected. Your clock code is showing 600-1600fps in release mode now for me.

Comment: Ok, but i also tried the game on my Xbox One, and there i have the choice between "App" and "Game",  and when i put it on "Game", it's almost 50% faster then as "App". On Xbox One i get the same results for my game btw (Release is much slower), just both are way slower than on my PC.

Comment: Yeah OK, IIRC XBox runs basically 3 operating systems (like layers). The game OS may have some optimizations over the general/application OS. I haven't worked on XBox, so that's just my rough understanding. But your game should be running much better irrespective of that setting.

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to invest in my code as much as you seemed to do. 
Now your code with the 2 for loops will fill the screen, and even beyond it, but my game will have to draw many more textures per frame, and most will probably be overlapping previous ones, especially in the outside levels, with lot of grass, trees, and other vegetation. Unfortunatly i cannot use the depthbuffer because all the textures may have partial opaque pixels. I could eventually draw the textures twice,

Comment: first only the full opaque pixels, from front to back, and use the depthbuffer,then draw them all again, using the same depthbuffer but only as read, and draw only the non opaque pixels this time, from back to front. Maybe this could even be faster,  i will test this at the end, once my game needs optimisation.

Comment: But you are right,  maybe i should first try to Simply draw all the textures in one frame, and only later optimize it if it's really needed. I will up vote your anwser, but i cannot mark it as the one who solved my problem, because it didn't answer why my code is slower in release mode.

Comment: Well when I run that code now in release mode, I'm getting 600-1000+fps.

Comment: Did you try my code, befor you change it, in debug and release, and was release also slower ?

Comment: I just tried your version, and this is Indeed Strange,  now i get 700 FPS in debug mode,  and about 1600 in release mode, this seems also to much difference in performance, but at least in the right direction (debug is slower than release). But Something Strange i found is, despite presenting the backbuffer to the screen without vertical synchronisation, when i go into full screen (shift+Win + enter keys) the frames get maxed at 60 FPS.

Comment: No I didn't try it in release mode, as soon as I ran it I saw that it was broken. It's meaningless to measure framerates when you have broken and unpredictable code determining framerate IMO.

Re: 60fps lock .. You're not running a really old version of Windows are you? I'm not sure about that issue.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 pro,  up to date.

Comment: I think i found the answer to my speed problem. I updated the main post.

Comment: Regarding your explanation of it running at 60 fps in fullscreen .. Are you using command lists? Which is a DX 12 feature. NVidia cards support command lists in DX11 but AMD do not, they only support Command Lists in DX12. But either way, you must explicitly use them, it's not automatic.

Comment: It seems that the CPU does not wait for the GPU to execute a draw call, regardless if using command lists or not, from what i read in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020638/rendering-in-directx-11